# Please help me with your inputs

Tags: iphone, ios4

I would like to know where i can learn about core data model. please explain me in simple words that how to work with core data model and it its uses.

really i feel very tough to understand about core data model.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should find a tutorial, if you don't understand a certain part of it ask for clarification on here, not a better tutorial, we'll do what you did Google it and just give you a tutorial Google comes up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this website, it covers alot of subjects regarding iOS development, if I remember correctly there is stuff on there about Core Data http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials